# Calendar with date and time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Is there any free 3rd party calendar that I can use for selecting date and time in my webpage. I found some but it was not for free. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it free from here:

http://www.west-wind.com/jqueryweb/jqueryDatepicker.aspx

DateTime Picker can be downloaded from her, you can pick time along with date:

http://www.projectcodegen.com/JQueryDateTimePicker.aspx

with alot of customizing options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to select time as well

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Calendar control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) in the ajax control toolkit.

Comment: I need to select time as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AjaxControlToolKit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/calendar/calendar.aspx) for your purpose.

Edit:

You can try ASP.NET [Timepicker](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221).

Comment: I need to select time as well